# Intellij error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError com/amazon/ion/system/IonBinaryWriterBuilder

Tags: java, intellij-idea

For a class I am taking, my professor gave me a program that I'll need to edit for the assignment, however I can never get it to run on my machine. I get the error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazon/ion/system/IonBinaryWriterBuilder
in ToolingStreamApiUtils.createIonWriter(ToolingStreamApiUtils.java:22)

Cause: class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy142 cannot be cast to class org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.DefaultExternalProject (com.sun.proxy.$Proxy142 and org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.DefaultExternalProject are in unnamed module of loader com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader @3db9b80d)
```

Whenever I try to reload the gradle for it. It uses java and gradle and builds in Intellij. I've tried many times to get it to work, including changing the Java SDK, reinstalling gradle, and reinstalling and rebuilding Intellij. Another solution suggested that I needed to update Android Studio, but even removing that plugin and using Intellij base doesn't work. The only solution I've managed to get to work in the past was running it on a VM, but that really slows down my computer and workflow. I use Windows if that helps. Does anyone have an idea as to what I can do to fix it. It doesn't seem like this is an error anyone else in the class has had, and even the TAs couldn't figure out the issue. Java SDK is corretto-1.8.